# Gravity center text not working for first child element of Gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'v created adapter with textview which set text to child elements in gridview. Below is my Adapter Code-

```
 class CustomAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter1(Context context,List<String> list)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                                                                  
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlie_textview, null);          
        }
        else
        {
            textView=(TextView)convertView;
        }
        textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(list.get(position));

        return textView;
    }   
    }
```

I set gravity of textview to center but my problem is that first child element of gridview not centered. I've tried using internal list layout of android device it works perfectly. Then what will be the problem? thanks in advance.

Below is my Xml layout-

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.urva.educationapp.BarakhadiActivity" >



  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"   
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="3dp"        
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"  >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Maintext"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_margin="2dp"
         android:textSize="60dp" />

     </RelativeLayout> 

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"           
        android:numColumns="3"    
        android:layout_gravity="right"            
        android:layout_weight="2"             
        >
    </GridView>   

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"  
    android:orientation="vertical"     
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>        

        <com.urva.educationapp.CustomView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="#fff"  />


  </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my textview xml file -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout    
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"     
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Paste xml code of your GridView and GridView's item layout. Adapter wont be useful to catch the error.

Comment: Another mistake I catch is you are returning TextVIew's object. You should return convertView (View class object).

Comment: hello friend, but when i use simple_list_item_1 internal device layout it works fine.

Comment: Where are you defining gridview item's textview ? I also need R.layout.singlie_textview file

Comment: then compare simple_list_item_1 and your item layout